# Making ArcGIS tool to generate ObjectIDs that start from Upper left rather than bottom left in Fishnet?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, objectid, spatial-sort

When I spatial join a fishnet with another fishnet, I see ObjectIDs start from bottom left of the feature rather than Upper left of features. How can I make ArcGIS to create feature class having records starting from Upper left of features?

Images:
What is happening:
[image: Example1]

What I need:
[image: Example2]

I know a tool "Spatial Sort" which does this. But I don't want to use that as I already have to apply many geo-processing tools on large data, and make it slower.

Any Idea?

Comment: You cannot control objectid values, period.  You can calculate a different integer field to contain the values you want, based on knowledge of the number of rows and columns in the fishnet, at the cost of adding a new column and calculating into it.

Comment: @Vince this is a workaround but not exactly the solution, because, when you run, subsequently, any gp tool result will be same(i.e., starting from bottom left).

Comment: You ***cannot*** control objectid values, so there is no point in trying.

Comment: I had to look this up about "cannot control objectid values" just for my own interest. This [site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459795/how-can-you-edit-the-objectid-of-a-row-in-an-arcgis-geodatabase) has some info about it.

Comment: I have created a python script that can do this, but only after you create the fishnet. But it sounds like you want to control the creation. Perhaps you could create a custom fishnet generation tool in Python?

Answer (score 2):

If the Sort Tool with Spatial_sort method is too slow, you might try this. Add a new field, long data type. Calculate it from the Objectid field. Perform the spatial join. Run the Sort Tool providing the new field as the sort_field. It should be in the same order as before the Spatial Join.